# Is there anyway to run Spring Boot via Cmd commands without building Jar?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've searched but got no answer.

I've tried to run like this:

```bash
mvn spring-boot:run
```

But it still compiles `jar` before running.

I just want to quickly run a Spring Boot project via CMD like I run through an IDE (like Intelij)

Any idea for that?

Comment: Your main issue is speed?

Comment: When I use `mvn spring-boot:run`, it compiles the code and puts the result in the target folder, but it doesn't create a jar. When I run using the IDE, it does mostly the same.

Comment: @cela: yes, everytimes I edit code, it need to compile again, it took time.  
scrhartley: not even close when compare run by IDE

Comment: Compile it once, then use `java -jar <your-spring-boot>.jar`

Answer (score 1):

use java to run

if use maven to package you can unzip the jar and run:

You need to ensure that the META-INF information is correct

```
java  -classpath /your-classpath:/your-classpath/lib/* org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

if you not use the maven, you can use the run it:

```
$ java -classpath ./target/classes/:./lib/* com.xxxx.YourApplicationMain
```

the lib is all of your import the jar

like:

```
./lib* = ./lib/path/spring-boot-starter-web-3.1.2.jar:./lib/path/tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.11.jar ....
```

If you use IDEA, a simple way is to directly copy and execute commands on the first line of IDE console

Comment: Can you give a more detail answer?

Comment: @mikenlanggio I have updated my answer and hope it is what you want